# Are superconductors primarily for DC transmission?

Tags: kinematics, electrical-resistance, superconductivity

I understand Superconductors can be beneficial due to their resistance to magnetic fields as in levitating bullet trains or MRI machines, but is our main interest for DC power distribution?

I see questions where people believe due to a super conductors zero resistance it would power a phone indefinitely without an additional power source.  Is it safe to say anything it powers is a resistor and this cannot be our interest?

Answer (score 0):

> [some] people believe...it would power a phone indefinitely without an additional power source. Is it safe to say anything it powers is a resistor and this cannot be our interest?

Correct. A superconductor can *transmit* power from point A to point B without any Ohmic loss, but it is not an infinite *source* of power. A superconducting magnet can act as a source of power, but only for a limited time. The magnet can *store* a finite amount of energy, but it does not *create* energy.

> is our main interest for DC power distribution?

I have not heard of any real-world example of a superconducting power transmission or distribution system. Superconductivity only occurs at extremely cold temperatures, and the cost of keeping the transmission line chilled to such temperature would *vastly* outweigh the cost of energy that is "lost" in an ordinary transmission line.

Comment: Although there are no superconducting long-distance transmission lines in the real world, we would definitely get some if they discovered room-temperature superconductors.

Comment: Also I wonder if the LHC uses superconductors for power transmission, since they have superconducting electromagnets *anyway*, and therefore already have a cooling system.

Comment: @user253751, Re, "LHC;" It _does_ use a bit of power... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider#Design